# Why ArraySpeciesCreate is called in Array.prototype.splice?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

ES6 mentioned [`ArraySpeciesCreate`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.splice) is called in [`Array.prototype.splice`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.splice) in step 12, and the later creates a new array according to is original array. Why `ArraySpeciesCreate` is required to be called to create a copy of the original array? Does `Array.prototype.splice` operate in the original array directly like below?

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
a.splice(0, 1); // a is [2, 3] after this statement
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why ArraySpeciesCreate is required to be called to create a copy of the original array?

It *doesn't* create a copy of the original array (more below).

> Does `Array.prototype.splice` operate in the original array directly...?

Yes.

`splice` does two things:

1. It modifies the array you call it on, and
2. It creates a *new* array that contains any entries you remove

`ArraySpeciesCreate` is used because of #2, so that with a subclassed array, you get back an instance of the subclass:

```js
class CustomArray extends Array {
}

let main = new CustomArray("a", "b", "c", "d");
let deleted = main.splice(1, 2);             // Remove and return b and c
console.log("main", main);                   // ["a", "d"]
console.log("deleted", deleted);             // ["b", "c"]
console.log(deleted instanceof CustomArray); // true
```

Note how the array we got back from `splice` is an instance of `CustomArray`. That's because of the use of [`ArraySpeciesCreate`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-arrayspeciescreate) that you flagged up in your question. From the description of `ArraySpeciesCreate` in the spec:

> The abstract operation `ArraySpeciesCreate` with arguments *originalArray* and *length* is used to specify the creation of a new Array object using a constructor function that is derived from *originalArray*.

Note that bit at the end. Basically, `ArraySpeciesCreate` uses the original array's `constructor` property to build the new array.